# Trouble connecting to wifi in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, internet, laptop, hp

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my HP Laptop. Unfortunately it cannot recognize my WiFi adapter. I have a cable between my modem and laptop, but this is a temporary solution and google search has not helped me resolved my issue. Do you have any advice?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's check for any driver packages that apply to your system:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

If you see a list of devices that need drivers, you can do this:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

You can also check which devices need drivers like this:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

From there, you should have enough information to get the necessary software installed to have WiFi and other features enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is very unlikely to solve the problem unless OP has some specific Broadcom device.

Comment: all of the drivers updated /: